# How can I use JPA Query Methods to return an OR condition with NULL?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Am trying to create a Query that either matches all rows that equal `tier` or are NULL. Using Query Methods as described in [Spring JPA Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods). The Default implementation below works if I just pass in the `tier`:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tier")
class UuTier {
    Long id;
    Long tierId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
class User {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tier_id")
    UuTier uuTier;
    // Other Relationships
}


public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {
  List<User> findByTier_Id(@Param("tier")Long tier);
}
```

What I need is something like this, which is throwing an error " No property null found for type User". Can I achieve this ask using Query Methods?:-

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {
  List<User> findByTierOrNull_Id(@Param("tier")String tier);
}
```

Comment: How about ``findByTierOrTierIsNull_Id``?

Answer (score 0):

Following up from one of the responders (who for some reason deleted her post) - I got this to work!!

```
@Query("SELECT entity FROM User entity LEFT JOIN UuTier uuTier ON entity.uuTier.tier = uuTier.tier"
        + " WHERE entity.uuTier.tier = :tier OR entity.uuTier.tier IS NULL")
public List<User> findByTierOrNull_Id(@Param("tier") Long tier);
```